How do I know when cats playing becomes actual fighting
I have two cats that, most of the time, get along just fine. However, I see them wrestling regularly (almost every day, and since I don't work from home it probably is every day) and this often seems to get a bit too heated I think.
It's often the same cat (T) that seem to start it, but I am pretty sure the other (C) doesn't mind too much (I once walked past a brawl, and C stopped to look at me even as T was hugging him and seemed to be chewing on his throat!!), and C's ears are not splayed back for most of it.
Sometimes though, C seems to have had enough and tries to leave. T tends to chase him for a while to continue, and this is when C's ears start getting splayed back and sometimes he hisses too. Problem is I've the impression this is getting more common, and I worry it's a problem in the making.
Questions:

What can I do to prevent it from going too far?
How do I know when it's gone far enough to be a true issue?
At what point am I going to have to perhaps outright separate the two?

I really don't want to have to separate them. They are an older pair that I adopted from the same family (because of divorce) and they have lived together their whole lives (they are 10 and 8 years old; T is older). They also get along just fine at all other times; neither seem scared of the other and when the brawls don't go too far they tend to end with them grooming each other for a few minutes then going their separate ways to nap.

This sounds like play where the cats have slightly different opinions regarding what is too much.
That is something completely normal and no cause for concern, even if some hissing and pinning of the ears is involved. There might even be some fur left on the floor afterwards here and there, as it tends to come off easy during roughhousing.
What you want to look for is behavior afterwards, the cats might avoid each other for a short while, but other than that no lasting consequences can be observed.
A very obvious sign that things aren't serious is that the 'attacking' cats attention can be redirected for a brief moment, e.g. you reprimanding them leading to their head turning in your direction, taking their eyes off the 'opponent'.
Note that this might not always be the case in a heated play chase situation that got a little out of hand, but it is never the case in a serious fight where one side is out for blood.
What we need to consider when analyzing such behavior is that among cats it is perfectly acceptable to solve disputes by mild violence, a good swat to the face (by another cat, never by a human!) in order to bring ones point across is nothing they hold grudges over.

A serious fight on the other hand is instantly recognizable as such, it will involve lots of screeching during the actual wrestling with strikes being very fast and brutal, you will notice hyper focused attention on each other that can't be redirected.
You will see pinned ears on both sides, puffed fur on at least one belligerent, and vocalization known as "singing", long-drawn sounds often changing in pitch which could be described as a mix of meowing and growling.
You will oftentimes notice blood drops on the battlefield afterwards, and it isn't uncommon for one side losing urine in fear.
Note that this isn't necessarily cause for immediate concern if this is a one-off occurrence, misunderstandings do happen sometimes, you might even observe strange situations where the defending cat is considering itself in a serious fight while the other side looks around in confusion as to where the threat might be, not realizing having caused the situation. Important is to look for a pattern of serious fights evolving, and increasingly reserved or even hostile behavior in day-to-day interactions.

That's a good an extensive answer. Most of the time, me just standing up from where I'm sitting gets T to break off from his attack and run away, though he tends to come back and continue if I just sit back down. I don't think they've ever avoided each other for long after a fight, and there is definitely a fair bit of fur lost (both are Siberians, with long fur, and T has a tendency to bite chunks of it from C's tail then swallow it, how T doesn't cough up hairballs daily I have no idea).

If they aren't drawing blood beyond an occasional accidental scratch, it is either play or strenuous discussion, not a fight.
